# How Splunk field contains double quote

Tags: splunk

When use Splunk, if we have log

```
key="hello"
```

Search in Splunk by

```
* | table a
```

we can see **hello** value

We might print out value with double quote, if we don't escape

```
key="hel"lo"
```

We'll see key value is **hel**. Value breaks before the position of quote

If try to escape double quote with **\**,

```
key="hel\"lo"
```

We'll see key value is **hel\**

Is use single quote around

```
key='hel"lo'
```

We'll see key value include single quotes, it's **'hello"lo'**. In this case, search criteria should be

```
* key="'ab\"c'" | table a
```

single quotes are parts of value

Question is how to include double quote as part of value?
Ideally, there should be a way to escape double quotes, input

```
key="hel\"lo"
```

should match the query

```
key="hel\"lo"
```

But it's not.

I have this problem for many years. Splunk value is dynamic, it could contain double quotes. I'm not going to use JSON my log format.

I'm curious why there is no answer in Splunk's official website.

Someone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
| makeresults 
| eval bub="hell\"o"
| table bub
```

Puts a double-quote mark right in the middle of the `bub` field

If you want to *search* for the double-quote mark, use `| where match()` like this:

```
| where match(bub,"\"")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not about the search. My question is how to keep double quote in field value. How to make Splunk know **key** value is **hel"lo**, not **hel**

Comment: @Yanbin - you told RichG this isn't about transforms, it's about search. But you tell me this isn't about search. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the data source would not generate events with embedded quotes without escaping them.  Otherwise, how would a reader know the quote is embedded and not mismatched?  This is the problem Splunk is struggling with.

The fix is to create your own parser using transforms.

In props.conf:

```
[mysourcetype]
TRANSFORMS-parseKey = parse_key
```

In transforms.conf:

```
[parse_key]
REGEX = (\w+)="(.*\".*)"
FORMAT = $1::$2
```

Of course, this regex is simplified.  You'll need to modify it to match your data.

Comment: Search can escape double quote, don't know why the index can't recognize the escaped double quotes. Like string type in any languages. `key="hel\"lo"`, it's not hard to identify the open and close quotes

Comment: Wait a minute.  You told @warren this question is not about search yet here you talk about search.  Is this a search question or not?  If not, then what is it?

Comment: The indexer *can* recognize escaped quotes if told to do so.  Put `KV_MODE=auto_escaped` in the props.conf file.